# Picking minimum datetime record in sql?

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a data as below:

```
act_desc              CustNO     Date_Time                      VASPK
GPRS Weekly Bundle  3012201312   2013-10-19 21:48:10.000    9588288
GPRS Weekly Bundle  3012201312   2013-10-19 21:48:03.000    9588286
GPRS Monthly Bundle 3012201312   2013-10-19 21:47:54.000    9588283
GPRS Monthly Bundle 3012201312   2013-10-19 21:47:33.000    9588281
GPRS Monthly Bundle 3012201312   2013-10-19 21:46:55.000    9588280
GPRS Monthly Bundle 3012201312   2013-10-19 21:46:43.000    9588278
GPRS Monthly Bundle 3012201312   2013-06-05 18:31:33.000    8582897
GPRS Monthly Bundle 3012201312   2013-05-04 20:18:54.000    8351398
GPRS Monthly Bundle 3012201312   2013-05-04 18:40:46.000    8350314
GPRS Monthly Bundle 3012201312   2013-05-04 18:40:25.000    8350308
GPRS Monthly Bundle 3012201312   2013-03-24 23:47:56.000    8069341
GPRS Monthly Bundle 3012201312   2013-03-24 23:47:42.000    8069340
GPRS Monthly Bundle 3012201312   2013-03-24 23:47:09.000    8069338
```

I want to pick records based on the minumum date time in last 30 days, that is I want to pick the datetime and go 30 days back to check if the same record exists, if exists then pick the minimum record else pick the one that is availabel.

Answer (score 0):

To get date 30 days back from today's date you can use dateadd function as:
`select dateadd(day, -30, getdate())`

and to select a minimum date based on given condition following query will work:

```
SELECT Min (date_time) 
FROM   yourtable
WHERE  CONVERT(DATE, date_time) >= CONVERT (DATE, Dateadd(day, -30, Getdate())) 
       AND CONVERT(DATE, date_time) <= CONVERT (DATE, Getdate())
```